# What´s happening with Deltaspike development?

Tags: java, seam3

The last release of deltaspyke was release in August, 2012. The development still continuous? The project have future?
I was thinking about use my faces CODI, because I don´t see any progres in deltaspike in recent months.
I would like to have an opinion about deltaspike, both community and the developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it yourself. Activity on the mailing list and in the repository ( https://github.com/apache/incubator-deltaspike/contributors ). We are using both CODI and DeltaSpike and are very happy. Last month the project graduated and is an Apache Top Level Project now ( https://twitter.com/DeltaSpikeTeam/status/324802824414306304 ).

Comment: My doubt it´s just because the development is very slow.

Comment: Then provide concrete feedback,... or join the effort to improve the documentation,...

Comment: The migration from CODI to Deltaspike is too expensive? Because, I think begin a project with deltaspike is risky.

Comment: You can wait until 1.0 and help to get there.